# Closeness of points in the irreducible decomposition of a C$^{*}$-algebra representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces. Let $\varphi\colon C(X)\to M_{n}(C(Y))$ be any $*$-homomorphism. If $\pi$ is an irreducible representation of $M_{n}(C(Y))$, then $\pi$ is unitarily equivalent to a point evaluation $\textrm{ev}_{y}$. The $*$-homomorphism $\textrm{ev}_{y}\circ\varphi\colon C(X)\to M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is a representation of $C(X)$. Since it's a finite-dimensional representation, we can find a unitary $u_{y}\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ and a set of points $X_{y}=\{x^{y}_{1},\ldots,x^{y}_{n}\}\subset X$ such that for all $f\in C(X)$,
$$
(\varphi\circ f)(y)=(\textrm{ev}_{y}\circ\varphi)(f)=u_{y}
\begin{pmatrix}
f(x^{y}_{1}) & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & f(x^{y}_{2}) & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & f(x^{y}_{n})
\end{pmatrix}
u_{y}^{*}.
$$

**My question is:**

> Does the Hausdorff distance of the set $\{x_{1}^{y},\ldots,x_{n}^{y}\}$ vary continuously in $y$? More precisely, if $y_{m}\to y$ in $Y$, does $D_{m}:=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\min_{1\leq j\leq n}d_{X}(x^{y}_{i},x^{y_{m}}_{j})\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$?

This question is motivated by the simpler case where $\varphi$ gives rise to continuous functions $\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{n}:Y\to X$ satisfying
$$
\varphi(f)=\begin{pmatrix}
f\circ\lambda_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & f\circ\lambda_{2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & f\circ\lambda_{n}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In this case for each $y\in Y$, $X_{y}=\{\lambda_{1}(y),\ldots,\lambda_{n}(y)\}$, and the result holds.

Comment: This question has been answered in the affirmative here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306383/closeness-of-points-in-the-irreducible-decomposition-of-a-c-algebra-repres